# org-mode: add a header to a table programmatically

Tags: r, emacs, org-mode, org-table

I have a table defined in org-mode:

```
#+RESULTS[4fc5d440d2954e8355d32d8004cab567f9918a64]: table
|  7.4159 | 3.0522 |  5.9452 |
| -1.0548 | 12.574 | -6.5001 |
|  7.4159 | 3.0522 |  5.9452 |
|  5.1884 | 4.9813 |  4.9813 |
```

and I want to produce the following table:

```
#+caption: Caption of my table
|        | group 1 | group 2 | group 3 |
|--------+---------+---------+---------|
| plan 1 |   7.416 |   3.052 |   5.945 |
| plan 2 |  -1.055 |  12.574 |    -6.5 |
| plan 3 |   7.416 |   3.052 |   5.945 |
| plan 4 |  5.1884 |  4.9813 |  4.9813 |
```

How can I accomplish that? Here is what I tried (in R):

```
#+begin_src R :colnames yes :var table=table :session  
data.frame(table)
#+end_src
```

But of course it doesn't work, here is what I get:

```
#RESULTS:
| X7.4159 | X3.0522 | X5.9452 |
|---------+---------+---------|
| -1.0548 |  12.574 | -6.5001 |
|  7.4159 |  3.0522 |  5.9452 |
|  5.1884 |  4.9813 |  4.9813 |
```

Any suggestions?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gets pretty close. first define this function:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(defun add-caption (caption)
  (concat (format "org\n#+caption: %s" caption)))
#+END_SRC
```

Next, use this kind of src block. I use python, but it should work in R too, you just need the :wrap. I passed your data in through the var, you don't need it if you generate the data in the block.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results value :var data=data :wrap (add-caption "Some really long, uninteresting, caption about data that is in this table.")
data.insert(0, ["", "group 1", "group 2", "group 3"])
data.insert(1, None)
return data
#+END_SRC
```

This outputs

```
#+BEGIN_org
#+caption: Some really long, uninteresting, caption about data that is in this    table.
|        | group 1 | group 2 | group 3 |
|--------+---------+---------+---------|
| plan 1 |   7.416 |   3.052 |   5.945 |
| plan 2 |  -1.055 |  12.574 |    -6.5 |
| plan 3 |   7.416 |   3.052 |   5.945 |
| plan 4 |  5.1884 |  4.9813 |  4.9813 |
#+END_org
```

and it exports ok too I think.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This question is so meta it's nearly impossible to search for, but the `:wrap` is perfect!